# Groovy - Replacing the variable value

Tags: java, groovy

1. Retrieve the String value from JSON and in that string, I want to replace the variable value in that one.

Below one I declared variables inside the class

```
def recordCount = '33'
```

Below one retrieve from Json and stored into a separate variable

```
def jsonString = '${recordCount}'
```

assert part

```
assert recordCount == JsonString
```

While executing I want to replace the `recordCount` value in the `jsonString`variable.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Assert console error

```
Unable to verify equal between actual object ’33’ and expected object ' "$recordCount" '
```

Comment: Use `"${recordCount}"`. `'` is for normal strings, `"` for `GString`s, and only the latter supports interpolation.

Comment: @ernest_k used double quotes but its not replaced, when I print the jsonString it returns "${recordCount}"

Comment: Please edit the question and add that to the post.

Comment: also `JsonString` vs `jsonString`. It really helps if you pay close attention when "minimizing" the actual problem, so no other problems appear and distract from the actual ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quoted strings if you want variable substitution.

```
~ $ cat prabu_groovy_substitution.groovy 
def recordCount = '33'
def jsonString = "${recordCount}"
assert jsonString == recordCount

println "jsonString is ${jsonString}"

~ $ 
~ $ groovy prabu_groovy_substitution.groovy 
jsonString is 33
```